# Log into external website with user name and password automatically in an iframe

Tags: forms, iframe, submit, single-sign-on

I have a project where I would like to be able to create an iframe.

In this iframe will be an external page to a ftp login page (spot for a username and password).

How can I automatically populate the external site's username and password fields and then automatically submit the form?

I am having trouble with this. Thanks

[image]

---

Question. Would this be possible with javascript injection?

http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/modify-iframe-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can access the contents of a frame using .contents()

Something like

```
$("#YourFrameId").contents().find("#tbUsername").val("Admin")
```

This may work but some browsers will not allow this due to security concerns (unless it's accessing fields within the same domain and port).

Comment: "some browsers"? **All** mainstream browsers implement the same origin policy.

Comment: They aren't on the same domain. They will be eventually, but not right now. Any other way possible? The site is an external site that we pay for access to upload documents, and we don't want users to have to log in every time they are in our intranet

Answer (score 0):

You can, by default, only do this if the page in the iframe is on the same domain. If the domains are different then the page hosting the iframe may not interact with the document of the page within the iframe.

If you control both pages you can set the iframe source to `yourpage.aspx?username=xxx&password=yyy` and modify `yourpage.aspx` to detect this invokation and logon.

You can also in modern browsers use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate between the fames with Javascript.